# Dependency Property with type of DoubleCollection crash app in winui 3

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, winui

i have a custom control in my winui 3 app and i have a dp called `LineStrokeDashArray` dp defined like this:

```
testControl : Control
{
public DoubleCollection LineStrokeDashArray
{
    get { return (DoubleCollection)GetValue(LineStrokeDashArrayProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LineStrokeDashArrayProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LineStrokeDashArrayProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LineStrokeDashArray", typeof(DoubleCollection), typeof(testControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(DoubleCollection)));

}
```

and in my style and ControlTemplate:

```
 <Line 
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Stretch="Fill"
       Stroke="{TemplateBinding LineStroke}"
       StrokeDashArray="{TemplateBinding LineStrokeDashArray}"
       StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
       StrokeStartLineCap="Square"
       StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding LineStrokeThickness}"
       X2="1" />
```

now when i want to use my control like this:

`<local:testControl LineStrokeDashArray="2,2" />`

my app crash, i also tried
`new PropertyMetadata(new DoubleCollection()));`
and my app still crashing. i dont know why this is happening, and since this is a winui 3 app, there is no more info for crash and i get this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aspYB.png)

---

Update:
sample app:

[App9.zip](https://github.com/WinUICommunity/WinUICommunity/files/13761523/App9.zip)

Comment: Avoid pasting images for texts. You should provide a fully reproducible project [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also show the exact error and stacktrace (the e parameter of the unhandled error event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is determined by the personality of [Shape.StrokeDashArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.shape.strokedasharray?view=winrt-22621) Property.

According to my test, you cannot bind a `DoubleCollection` to more than one shape!

Comment: yes, binding to more than one shape cause issue, however why this is working in wpf? https://github.com/ghost1372/HandyControls/blob/develop/src/Shared/HandyControl_Shared/Controls/Other/Divider.cs   https://github.com/ghost1372/HandyControls/blob/develop/src/Shared/HandyControl_Shared/Themes/Styles/Base/DividerBaseStyle.xaml

Comment: WPF is out of the question and [DoubleCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.doublecollection?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)(WPF) and [DoubleCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.doublecollection?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4)(WindowsAppSDK) are different, especially the [Freezable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) Class in WPF.

Comment: I used a converter and issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a single `DoubleCollection` `DependencyProperty` to several `ListView`s inside a single custom control and it works. So it seems that binding it to several `Line`s is what is crashing your app.

What you can do is create internal `DoubleCollection`s for each `Line` you have and apply the public `DoubleCollection` to them.

Comment: I implemented all property, just i removed them here for short question...  if i remove  `LineStrokeDashArray="2,2"` from control  `<local:testControl/>`  app will be work so this is issue with LineStrokeDashArray

Comment: That is weird. I actually created a sample app with your code, and it doesn't crash.

Comment: i uploaded a demo app, can you run it? https://github.com/WinUICommunity/WinUICommunity/files/13761523/App9.zip

Comment: I used a converter and i returned a new DoubleCollection and issue fixed